# Exporting alerts json data using Grafana API in Grafana v10

Tags: python, grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-api

I am using Grafana cloud v10.0.3 and could not find any way to exports alerts json data. I tried to write a python script to access alerts json data but it is not showing any output. Below is the python script

```
import requests
import json

# Replace this with your actual token
token = "api token"

grafana_url = "https://domain.grafana.net"
alert_name = "NetworkDevice Down" //alert name

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(f"{grafana_url}/api/alerts", headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    alerts = response.json()
    for alert in alerts:
        if alert['name'] == alert_name:
            print(json.dumps(alert, indent=4))
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Grafana v10, the endpoint for retrieving alerts has been changed. Instead of /api/alerts, you need to use /api/v2/alerts to access the alerts API. Additionally, the response format has also been updated.

Modify your code as follows:

```
import requests
import json

# Replace this with your actual token
token = "api token"

grafana_url = "https://domain.grafana.net"
alert_name = "NetworkDevice Down"  # alert name

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(f"{grafana_url}/api/v2/alerts", headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    alerts = response.json()["results"]
    for alert in alerts:
        if alert['name'] == alert_name:
            print(json.dumps(alert, indent=4))
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
```

The main changes include:

```
Updating the endpoint from /api/alerts to /api/v2/alerts.
Accessing the alerts using response.json()["results"].
```

Make sure to replace "api token" and "https://domain.grafana.net" with your actual API token and Grafana URL respectively.

With these changes, the script should be able to retrieve and print the alerts JSON data for the specified alert name.

Comment: I tried your suggested way but it shows this output "Request failed with status code 404"